# How do I implement tab completion in node.js shell?

Tags: javascript, shell, node.js

I was looking for this feature in node.js and I haven't found it.
Can I implement it myself? As far as I know, node.js doesn't load any file at it's startup (like Bash does with `.bashrc`) and I haven't noticed any way to somehow override shell prompt.

Is there a way to implement it without writing custom shell?

Comment: AFAIK there is not autocomplete option for the v8 terminal. Maybe tools such as [with-readline](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2005/withreadline.html) can be helpful to you, however.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could monkey-patch the REPL. Note that you *must* use the callback version of the `completer`, otherwise it won't work correctly:

```
var repl = require('repl').start()
var _completer = repl.completer.bind(repl)
repl.completer = function(line, cb) {
  // ...
  _completer(line, cb)
}
```

Comment: this method didn't work for me. What worked better is to provide a "completer" function in the options for repl.start({}) - https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options

Comment: ^ I had to use the callback version for it to work, but it does work.

Answer (score 9):

Just as a reference.

`readline` module has `readline.createInterface(options)` method that accepts an optional `completer` function that makes a tab completion.

```
function completer(line) {
  var completions = '.help .error .exit .quit .q'.split(' ')
  var hits = completions.filter(function(c) { return c.indexOf(line) == 0 })
  // show all completions if none found
  return [hits.length ? hits : completions, line]
}
```

and

```
function completer(linePartial, callback) {
  callback(null, [['123'], linePartial]);
}
```

link to the api docs: http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options

Answer (score 0):

You can implement tab functionality using completer function like below.

```
const readline = require('readline');

/*
 * This function returns an array of matched strings that starts with given
 * line, if there is not matched string then it return all the options
 */
var autoComplete = function completer(line) {
  const completions = 'var const readline console globalObject'.split(' ');
  const hits = completions.filter((c) => c.startsWith(line));

  // show all completions if none found
  return [hits.length ? hits : completions, line];
}

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  completer: autoComplete
});

rl.setPrompt("Type some character and press Tab key for auto completion....\n");


rl.prompt();
rl.on('line', (data) => {
  console.log(`Received: ${data}`);
});
```

**Reference** :
https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2018/10/nodejs-readlinecreateinterfaceoptions_2.html